# sort TextView in GridView

Tags: java, android

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2Q0.png)

I have 50 TextViews with mixed colors(colors in ArrayList).How I can sort it by colors?

For example red in first Column....

This is Adapter.java:

```
   public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements 
   View.OnClickListener 
  {
     Context mcontext;
    List<Colors> colorlist ;
   LayoutInflater lInflater;


  public Adapter(Context applicationContext, List<Colors> colorlist1) {
    colorlist = colorlist1;
    mcontext=applicationContext;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
 public int getCount() {
    return colorlist.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
    return colorlist.get(position);
 }
```

I must use this positions for sort?

```
@Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v=convertView;
    if (v== null) {
        v= lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }


    Colors col=   getColors(position);
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvv)).setBackgroundColor(col.colors);
    return v;
 }
 Colors getColors(int position) {
    return (Colors) getItem(position);
}
```

Comment: I don't get you, what kind of sorting are you talking about? Alphabetical, Hex..?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi sorry... I changed u can see

Comment: You have to keep your colors as a string and sort them according to that. You can do alphabetical sorting on name with that

Comment: I can't see any ordering criteria in your code. You want to order colors by Argb maybe?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi  I cant add here more code:(I had change again u can see

Comment: @Sura, did you check my answer?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Maybe I didnt understand but I add that in onClick().. this dont work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by hex code, you can use Comparable interface:

```java
 public void sortListByArgb() {
        SortableColor[] myColors;
        myColors = new SortableColor[4];
        myColors[0] = new SortableColor("#ff0000");
        myColors[1] = new SortableColor("#ff9000");
        myColors[2] = new SortableColor("#ff6000");
        myColors[3] = new SortableColor("#ff3000");
        Arrays.sort(myColors);
        for (SortableColor s : myColors) {
            System.out.print("---- Hex: " + s.colorHex + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static class SortableColor implements Comparable<SortableColor> {
        private String colorHex;

        public SortableColor(String hexCode) {
            super();
            colorHex = hexCode;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull SortableColor sortableColor) {
            return colorHex.compareTo(sortableColor.colorHex);
        }
    }
```

Result is:

- Hex: #ff0000
- Hex: #ff3000
- Hex: #ff6000
- Hex: #ff9000

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Result is: ---- Hex: #ff0000
              ---- Hex: #ff3000
              ---- Hex: #ff6000
              ---- Hex: #ff9000